# Is "goods" countable?

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns

I am referring to *goods* as in *services and goods provided*. I came across [this definition](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/tender-document.html) (emphasis mine):

> tender document:
>
> A written invitation sent to potential suppliers of **a good or service** to inform them about the information required for the buyer to choose among them. Issuing a tender document typically begins the tender process by which a business selects qualified and interested suppliers based on such things as their price, availability and proposed delivery terms.

The use of *good* as a countable noun seems wrong to me. Is *good* used correctly here, is it a countable noun? Can one provide *a good*?

EDIT:   Google returns  9,790,000 hits for "suppliers of a good". Does that mean I have to accept it as "correct"? Does no one else feel it is wrong?

Comment: In a fixed phrase like _goods and services_, when one wants an indefinite singular, _a good or service_ will do. It's legal and therefore marked, however. Leave it alone unless you're a lawyer. **Summary:** Idioms can be, or do, anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED has

> **C.** *noun*
> **III.** A particular thing that is good.
> **7.** Property or possessions; now in more restricted sense, movable property.
> **a.**
> (a) *plural*
> (b) The plural form occurs as a sing.: Property, an amount of property. (Cf. sense C. 7d)

So yes, the plural form can occur as a singular, and mean a certain amount of property; a thing. In my experience it's restricted to legal wording where *goods* may **either** have its customary meaning of "movable property" as what is almost a mass noun **or** mean two or more singular *good*s [consider the phrase *goods and services* in the context of your quote].  Consequently the word *good* is used to mean "a thing" as a single entity and remove that ambiguity.

I would certainly not recommend using the singular *good* in normal use!

Just for the record, sense C. 7d is related, but now obsolete:

> †**d.** *singular* Money. ***(a) great good*** : a great sum of money. ***marriage good:*** a marriage portion. *Obs.*
>
> **marriage portion** n. a portion or dowry given to a bride at the time of her marriage.

Comment: Oh. John wrote his comment while I was preparing this. At least we're saying the same thing.